# Filling a 2D array in C twice, first with one number in randomized positions and then fill the rest with randomized numbers

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm totally lost here, i'm a C newbie and i'm just learning about 2D arrays and i got an assignment about making an array and filling it with -1 in random positions, and then filling the rest of it with random numbers from 0 to 100.

I've been trying different functions and i've created arrays but i can only completely fill them with random numbers.

My main problem is the first step, making it fill itself with -1 in random positions, where should i start? i've been searching but i cant find something that makes this. I'm asking out of desperation.

Comment: Sorry, we don't write code for people. Show us what you have, and we can help you with the part that doesn't work.

Comment: Pick a few row and column indices at random. Then complete the rest where there is no `-1`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a "do my homework" site.

Comment: I have a problem with the question: after ***filling** it with -1 in random positions* what then is *the rest of it*? If you had posted your attempt you might not be losing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we wont code for you, **instead** I can push you in the right direction however your description lacks information so I will tell you in what direction you should go.

1. Usually you need a **seed for your randomization**, so your mentors can test your code if it is valid with their randomization seed and if the results are correct.
2. You should make a function which will return the **number of elements**, which you will later fill (with the next function).
3. Make another function which will return the **index of the element** of the array that you want to fill and fill it with a random number (1-100). Repeat this the number of times you got as a result from the last function.
4. Fill every already **non-filled** element with -1.

I think I gave you more than enough. Remember that **only YOU** can teach yourself how to code trough numerous and numerous amount of problems. :)

Comment: Thanks this is all i needed. I get it this is the first and last time i ask without a code to post. Will post it when i have something decent.

Answer (score 0):

First zero out the array. For random position, get a random number for the row, and a random number for the column. For the second part, only overwrite the zeroes, not the -1's.